# Fixed header of slider

Tags: html, jquery, css, slider

I can't figure out how to set position 'fixed' button in my slider when i scroll down.
Please help.
I've tried to set in css '**.slider-item button{position:fixed}**' but it did't work.

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-fog-bf8rm?file=/src/index.css

Comment: i think you need `position: sticky` with `top:0;`

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these properties to your button and **remove** *overflow: hidden* from your *.slider-container*

```
.slider-item button {
  position: sticky;
  top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it work. But how i can save overflow:hidden prop?

Comment: @DavidAbramov replace it with `overflow: clip;`